# sqlite: create FTS table and insert data from csv file in one single statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to write a sql command which can perform

1. creating a FTS table
2. import data from a csv file into the new FTS table

I found people have done these in 2 steps.
But I need it to be one statement since I will use it in sqlite execution as below.
Thanks a lot

```
    sql = """"""
    connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: I am curious to see an SQL statement that can perform import from a CSV file